# High RAM usage in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, ram

While using only 5-6 tabs of Chrome, my RAM usage is about 95%-97% and always stays above 90%. My laptop has 8GB of RAM.

[image: System monitor showing high RAM usage]

Comment: Check which process consuming most of the RAM, type `top` or, `htop` and paste the result.

Comment: launch a terminal by issuing     ctrl + alt + t    then run above mentioned `top` and or `htop`

Comment: `ps -e -o pid,cmd,%mem --sort=-%mem` first 10 would do I think.

Comment: Please [edit] and post the output of `ps -e -o pid,cmd,%mem --sort=-%mem | head` in your original question as @kortewegdevries suggested.

Comment: Your RAM and SWAP usage is high. Your SWAP is a little too small. Edit your question and show me the `top` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` outputs. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I actually have the same issue (high memory usage). Running `htop` or `top` doesn't return much useful data - the process using the most memory is Chrome but only 3.5% of 12GB of RAM. However system monitor shows 10.1GB used up. Running `free -m` seems to reveal that 8.78GB is used for buff/cache and 7.2GB by `shared` What does this 'shared' mean and why is it taking up so much memory?

Comment: kill -3 $(pidof gnome-shell)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, this command really helped me! `ps -e -o pid,cmd,%mem --sort=-%mem`
Elasticsearch alone consumed 45% of RAM

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1336635)